What is the XAML syntax to pass several enum values to a converter parameter in MAUI?
I am able to provide one enum value as a ConverterParameter like so:
Text="{Binding TextValue, Converter={mct:TextConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:MyEnum.Value1}}"

Or several values of simple types like so:
Text="{Binding TextValue, Converter={mct:TextConverter}, ConverterParameter='1|2'}"

But I have not figured out even after some research how tot provide several values of an enumeration type (flag enum).
What I am trying to do is something like:
ConverterParameter = {local:MyEnum.Value1|local:MyEnum.Value2}

Maybe I should use an array of object instead of trying of providing flag values as it is not supported in XAML syntax? Thanks for any input on this

If your converter is supposed to take multiple values to convert the value, you should not be using Converter's to begin with, you should be doing it in your ViewModel itself.

Interesting, I am quite unexperienced with XAML to be honest and I don't quite see what would be wrong with providing multiple values to converter parameters would you mind giving more information about the reasons for that ?

A converter generally converts one value to another, you could send multiple items in it as a class that you create and then use that data as you please, but if you want to send multiple items you can't

You may also try using IMultiValueConverter with multi-bindings, see this answer.

You need to handle the flags in your Model or ViewModel. XAML is not C#, so you cannot use the pipe (|) to use multiple flags in a binding expression or directly as an expression for a converter parameter.
However, what you can do is something like this in C#:
[Flags]
public enum MyEnum
{
    Value1,
    Value2,
    Value3
}

public partial class MyModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private MyEnum _flags;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _textValue;

    public MyModel()
    {
        Flags = Value1 | Value3;
        TextValue = "Some Text";
    }
}

And then consume the Flags property as a binding argument to the ConverterParameter in your XAML:
<Label>
    <Label.Text>
        <Binding
            Path="TextValue"
            Converter="{mct:TextConverter}"
            ConverterParameter="{Binding Flags}" />
    </Label.Text>
</Label>

